# HTML Color Picker that changes root: css variable

Tags: jquery, html, colors, picker, css-variables

I am trying to create an accessibility tool on my website that would allow a user to use a HTML5 Color input to define their desired accent color for the website. As of right now I have preset options that use some javascript to just switch in their css file. To make these individual files easier to handle I decided to define root: variable colors. This works just fine accept now I am trying to set the root: variables color with the input from the color picker. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the code of what you've tried in snippet or fiddle? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I went ahead and pushed my most recent changes to my GitHub https://github.com/chris1000/JCHSAccuracy-FBLA Thanks so much for the replay! You'll find the color switching code under just about any .html file (except 404 and mail-success). The color switching code happens on the front end under the "<!--Tools Modal-->" and in the "trendbiz-option.js" file located under ~/js/.